# Which carpet for a swivel chair to roll easily?

Tags: carpet

I'm about to replace an old carpet in my new house. I need the new carpet to be very well adapted for a swivel chair to roll on it easily. Not that I spend my time rolling when working, but I hate when I feel that my chair is like planted in the ground.

Which kind of carpet do you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ease of rolling is a function of the surface and the wheels. There are [casters](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Shepherd-2-in-Hooded-Ball-Stem-Caster-9516/100185391#.Uf0VxaVPy44) for rolling furniture that are specifically intended for carpets rather than hard floors

[image: caster]

Additionally, low pile loop carpeting is used in offices because it wears well and is better for rolling furniture.

[image: chair mat]

If you still have difficulty, there are [chair mats](http://www.staples.com/Staples-Low-Pile-Carpet-Chair-Mat-Lip-36-inch-x-48-inch/product_561162) made of plastics that sit under a desk and chair over the carpeting to allow easier rolling

Comment: the chair mat also protects the carpet from the localized wear due to wheel rolling, and the inevitable spills of coffee, lunch etc.

Comment: the chair mat was my first thought too, no reason to limit yourself to tight weave carpet without much padding